# Statistics - Uniform sample vs. Representative sample

Tags: statistics, sampling

I have a question concerning two different samples, with the first being more uniform that the second.

a) Chance errors are likely to be smaller...

- using the first set of subjects
- using the second set of subjects
- no way to tell

b) Bias is likely to be smaller...

- using the first set of subjects
- using the second set of subjects
- no way to tell

What I think:

When our samples are more uniform, we compromise representativeness. For example, if we use a random sample, that sample tends to be more representative of the whole population, and thus less uniform than, say, a sample of a group of your friends. So, I think a) is using the first set of subjects (the more uniform set), and b) is using the second set of subjects (the less uniform set). Can someone confirm if my justifications are correct? Thanks!

Comment: By "more uniform", do you mean the _probability distribution_ by which they were chosen is more uniform, or the things you're interested in measuring are more uniform?

Comment: No, as in the variability in the sample is "small" -- the subjects tend to have similar traits.

Comment: In that case I think you've got it.  Using a sample taken from the local Republican club in a poll to ascertain the political sentiments of the community isn't a good idea, but it's more uniform than a sample taken from the Census Bureau's list of all members of the community.

Comment: So, chance errors are probably smaller in more uniform samples, right? This is because we know that the more uniform sample has individuals who are more similar to each other, correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$